# Reading a file line by line in Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to make a website that will either answer one question or upload a .txt file with one question per line then read it, then make it download this using nothing but javascript(not jquery or node.js) and HTML5:

- What to eat: Tacos
- How to sit: Crisscross

Rather than the input file which is

- What should I eat
- How should I sit

How would I do this, I am totally clueless. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random Facts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Random Facts & Stuff</h1>
    <p>To ask a question, simply ask it through the input bar below, or, if 
you want, you can upload a file and then hit download, then it will 
download a file.txt with the questions you put in and then the answers 
after the colin:</p>
    <br>
    <p>Ask a question here</p>
    <input type="text" id="question1" />
    <br>
    <p>Or upload a file here</p>
    <input type="file" id="question2" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="go">Go!</button>
    <script>
    // Do this for when the button is clicked
    document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {

      // Check whether or not the first input field is blank
      if (document.getElementById('question1').value.length == 0) {
        // Do this if the first text field is empty, aka, read the file.

        // create the file reader.
        var reader = new FileReader();
      } else {
        // If the text field is not empty, do this.


        alert("Text");
      }
    }
      var reader = new FileReader();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: You should search for a tutorial on interactive web applications

Comment: No idea about what are your trying to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Node.js you can not use filesystem that`s why you should use only "answer the question" without loading the .txt file.

If you want to show the second question after the first you can:
1) use callbacks
2) read about generators (es6) or use Promises (or await functions).